# How to use re.search on a list?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have tried to change the re.search to re.match and so. But still it will show "No match result" no matter what I type.
I think there could be a problem in the code, since I made this code without fully comprehend the concept behind it.
Basically, I am trying to do a "search engine" to look for all the matching name if a word is given and matches one of the word in the names. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
import re
searchlist=[ *insert name here* ]

word_s = input("Search : ")

search_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(searchlist), re.I|re.M)

result = re.search(search_list, word_s)

if result:
    print("Match Result: ", result.group())
else:
    print("No match result.")
```

Comment: Looks like your searchlist is somehow invalid. Could you provide your test example?

Comment: Your approach will only work if the search terms start and end with letters or digits.

Comment: `searchlist=[("Fundamentals of Organic Chemistry, International Edition"),("Engineering Mechanics: Statics In SI Units")]`
This is part of it.

Comment: Well. It works. Try printing `word_s` maybe there's something wrong the input. Like trailing space or sth

Comment: If I input "fundamental", it doesn't show "Fundamentals of Organic Chemistry, International Edition, unless I inserted the name fully tho. But then the result printed is in lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last comment shows the problem:

In your code, `searchlist` is a list of the search terms (the things the regex searches for), *not the list of strings to be searched*.

For example:

```
searchlist = ["Fundamentals", "Engineering"]
search_list = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(searchlist), re.I|re.M)
```

Now `search_list` is `\b(?:Fundamentals|Engineering)\b`, so it can be used as regex that will find if any of those terms appears in `word_s`

```
result = re.search(search_list, word_s)
```

You want to do the exact opposite:

```
books = ["Fundamentals of Organic Chemistry, International Edition", "Engineering Mechanics: Statics In SI Units"]
word_s = input("Search for: ")
word_re = re.compile(r"\b{}\b".format(word_s), re.I)
for book in books:
    if re.search(word_re, book):
        print("First Match Result: ", book)
        break # Abort search after first match
else:         # Only executed if the for loop was exhausted
    print("No match result.")
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks! But what if I want to find all the result?

Comment: Then don’t break after a match. In that case, however, the `else` clause doesn’t work anymore. You could use a list to append all the results to and check if‘s empty afterwards.